# copy a column in a filtered range to another column, partially correct, partially irrational

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy column 19 to column 36 in a filtered range, however the results are only partially correct. As for the other part, I have no idea why it turns out that way.

I clear out column 36 first, printout the value and value2 of one problematic row (R1092) to make sure its empty. then I print out the value and value2 of col 19 that row. cells(1092, 19)'s value and value2 both are 109872. then I copy col 19 to col 36, printout the value and value2 of Cells(1092, 36), both are 60000. I tried to copy with value and value2, the results are the same.

This issue really annoys me. Appreciate any idea how this happens.

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=DScolumn, Criteria1:="<>Revlon EDI"

      ActiveSheet.Range("AJ2:AJ" & countrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Clear
      MsgBox ("The qtty 36 is " & ActiveSheet.Range("AJ1092").Value)
    MsgBox ("The qtty 36 value2 is " & ActiveSheet.Range("AJ1092").Value)
      MsgBox ("The qtty 19 is " & ActiveSheet.Range("S1092").Value)
      MsgBox ("The qtty 19 value2 is " & ActiveSheet.Range("S1092").Value2)
      ActiveSheet.Range("AJ2:AJ" & countrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value2 = _
        ActiveSheet.Range("S2:S" & countrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value2
    MsgBox ("The qtty 36 is " & ActiveSheet.Range("AJ1092").Value)
    MsgBox ("The qtty 36 value2 is " & ActiveSheet.Range("AJ1092").Value)
```

Comment: Just a quick note, you may prefer to also (or instead) do `Debug.print "The qtty...."`, instead of a message box.  That's just because once you get rid of the msgbox, there's not a record of anything.  Using `debug.print` will send that line to your Immediate Window, so after the macro is done, you can see the different values that were outputted.  (Press `CTRL+G` with the VB Editor open.)

Comment: Thanks. I'm really not familiar with `debug.print` yet

Comment: And I tried to copy like below, the result (1092, 36) is empty.   `Set newrange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
          newrange.Columns(19).Copy Destination:=newrange.Columns(36)`

Comment: There really isn't much to be "familiar with" about `Debug.Print` - Just open the Immediate Window and treat it like a console.